# Am I using this switch case incorrectly?

Tags: c++, c++11

So the idea of this program is to get the users input in the form of a Roman Numeral up to 4999. I decided to use a switch case to loop through an string of input. The problem is when I put in a value like 99 which would be XCIX it returns -101. Any help is grateful.

```
int number = 0, M = 1000, D = 500, C = 100, L = 50, X = 10, V = 5, I = 1;

for (int i = 0; i < roman.length(); i++)
{

    switch (roman[i])
    {
    case 'M': number += 1000; break;
    case 'D': if (roman[i + 1] != 'D' && i + 1 < roman.size()) 
                  number -= 500;
              else
                  number += 500;
        break;
    case 'C': if (roman[i + 1] != 'C' && i + 1 < roman.size()) 
                  number -= 100;
              else
                  number += 100;
        break;
    case 'L': if (roman[i + 1] != 'L' && i + 1 < roman.size())  
                  number -= 50;
              else
                  number += 50;
        break;
    case 'X': if (roman[i + 1] != 'X' && i + 1 < roman.size())  
                  number -= 10;
              else
                  number += 10;
        break;
    case 'V': if (roman[i + 1] != 'V' && i + 1 < roman.size())  
                  number -= 5;
              else
                  number += 5;
        break;
        case 'I':
            if (roman[i + 1] != 'I' && i + 1 < roman.size())  
                number -= 1;
            else
                number += 1;
            break;
    }

}
return number;
```

Comment: When `i` is `roman.length() - 1`, you've got a problem.

Comment: Your `&&` statements should be reserved. Check length before indexing.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart I tried what you said and it did not make a change to my out put as it is still giving me -101

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart: What do you mean by "reserved"?

Comment: The `size` test is actually unnecessary, if the string is NUL-terminated.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I believe he means reversed

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Switching the order of the arguments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Roman numerals count negative only when they appear before a digit with *higher* value.  Being *different* is not enough.

Comment: Oh ok I see what you mean, yea that is definitely what is giving me issues, thank you, I will get right on fixing that and see what happens. Thank you.